# What is the IOTA transaction data structure?

Tags: transaction, legacy-protocol

I'm vaguely familiar with Bitcoin's UTXO-based transaction structure and Ethereum's account-based/gas-including transaction structure.

What does an IOTA transaction contain?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy protocol and given the latest updates it might make sense to only keep recent Shimmer, ShimmerEVM and IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Trinary Note

- In the "normal" world we have bytes & bits, where 1 byte is 8 bits giving us 2^8 = 256 possible data values for 1 byte.
- In the trinary world we have trytes & trits, where 1 tryte is 3 trits giving us 3^3 = 27 possible data values for 1 tryte. **This is what IOTA uses to stores its transaction data.**

#### Transaction Composition

One IOTA transaction consists of **2673 trytes**. Note, however, that a user will usually broadcast a collection of multiple transactions (also called a bundle). One bundle *could* consist of

1. Withdrawal transaction (acquire funds to be spent from some address)
2. Payment transactions (pay some other address a sub or total amount of the funds withdrawn)
3. Change transaction (deposit unspent funds back to one of the user's addresses)

Note that bundles are not restricted to a specific number of transactions. For exmaple, one could have a bundle that consists of just one transaction (when a value of 0 is "transferred").

The data segments within one transaction are as follows.

*Core Data*

1. **Signature Message Fragment** contains the transaction signature =  **2187 trytes**
2. **Address** is either receipt address (if value > 0) or withdrawal address (if value < 0) = **81 trytes**
3. **Value** is the amount of IOTA transferred = **27 trytes**
4. **Obsolete Tag** is some arbitrary user-defined value = **27 trytes**
5. **Time Stamp** of when the transaction was issued = **9 trytes**
6. **Current Index** of this transaction in its bundle = **9 trytes**
7. **Last Index** is the total number of transactions in the bundle = **9 trytes**

*Hashes*

8. **Bundle Hash** is the hash of the entire bundle = **81 trytes**
9. **Trunk Hash** is the hash of the 1st transaction referenced/approved = **81 trytes**
10. **Branch Hash** is the hash of the 2nd transaction referenced/approved = **81 trytes**

*Another Tag*

11. **Tag** is another arbitrary user-defined value = **27 trytes**

*Additional Time Stamps*

12. **Attachment Time** is the time stamp for when PoW is completed = **9 trytes**
13. **Attachment Time (lower bound)** is a slot for future use = **9 trytes**
14. **Attachment Time (upper bound)** is a slot for future use = **9 trytes**

*Proof-of-Work Data*

15. **Nonce** is the PoW nonce of the transaction = **27 trytes**

**Additional Links**

[https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/.../controllers/TransactionViewModel.java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/master/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/controllers/TransactionViewModel.java)
https://github.com/alon-e/iotaWayback
https://iota.readme.io/docs/the-anatomy-of-a-transaction

Comment: Actually, the Nonce has been reduced to 27 trytes, and the remaining part of the (old) nonce is used for a second Tag field (27 trytes) and three timestamp fields (9 trytes each)

Comment: @mihi Do you have a source? Then I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: iri commit: https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/commit/2c7a2c7010031ed329af63d27842892cc36b4fa6

Comment: Small clarification: 8. is the hash of the fields 2 to 7 of the entire bundle (it obviously cannot contain itself, the signature, or one of the other hashes, but it also does not include the additional timestamps)