# How do I decode the value (eg. 10i) in the signatureMessageFragment?

Tags: transaction

{'findTransactionsObjects': {'trytes': [TryteString(b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duration': 0}}

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/100/what-is-the-iota-transaction-data-structure) to see the structure of a transaction.

The value exchanged in a transaction is not encoded in the signatureMessageFragment but has its own field. In this transaction *value = +1i*.

In output transactions (txs with positive value, txs with receiving addresses) the signatureMessageFragment is used to store a message. In this case:

> "PBRBWBICLBNBCCLBRBACLBUBACSBOBCBNBKBBCHCMBTBZBSBCCHCOBLBCCZBYBKBNBVB9CZBLBRBGCGCACACBC9CNBICRBLBXBDCLBTBYBYBXBSBCCICYBCBLBACBCVBXBNBRBACCCVBYBYBUBUBKBECXBICZBSBICTBQBHCNBUBECICTBFC"

which does not seem to make sense in ASCII, probably is some JSON object but I'm not sure about this.

You can also notice that the *obsolete tag* has been modified: this happens during the bundle finalization to avoid the 'M-bug' (you don't want any 'M' in your bundle hash, it depends on the signature scheme).

If you follow that structure you can get every field as follows:

Signature/MessageFragment:
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

Address:
SQGACXMNQCXHIAQPHIYCSW9XDWRHVSXZTM9YRQABHRIPGNYLBDQOWWRVQFLMUIN99NQYFOSIWSOURQAFW

Value:
A99999999999999999999999999

Obsolete tag:
POTRYFEE9999999999999999999

Timestamp:
UHJJWZD99

Current index:
999999999

Last index:
C99999999

Bundle hash:
UYEEOGQFTAEQFHGYYGSPBFSBUXDIG9XINSZGOHXAFSGWCITRLYNALCSGCC99BZFIUXLXYCGYLVDLPCRDB

Trunk tx:
KPGHEJAVYTBLZXK9OBJYDEZDMMCDAB9NALHJPKHSIALKLCYVIVYEISOYLQJBEGLAOWDDBUEDYSCS99999

Branch tx:
HOJVMKPLQRIZAOAMSCHNEYDAVKHGOEEIWUAHTVDAGPPGV9YUOQACHDFGMCXLVZYTE9IGRJYSQZRYIG999

Tag:
ENTRYFEE9999999999999999999

Attachment timestamp:
MQUPC9PLE

Attachment timestamp lower bound:
999999999

Attachment timestamp upper bound:
MMMMMMMMM

Nonce:
ATIFLCTLPYCILDPJTLLEJYETPEO