# Accessing JSON message from IRI node API using Python 3

Tags: iri-node, tangle, iri-legacy-api, attach-to-tangle, python

I am using one command tangle. The tangle is running on Ubuntu machine. From the list of APIs given for [IRI node](https://docs.iota.org/docs/node-software/0.1/iri/references/api-reference), I'm trying to broadcast a transaction. For this, the first step is to get **getTransactionsToApprove** which returns **trunkTransaction** and **branchTransaction** and I have to assign that value to **attachToTangle** API.
I am getting the correct output from **getTransactionsToApprove** API:

```
{'trunkTransaction': 'NTCYZTAJTVJIAQW9JXUJCACYPHNMESWGWTANQQZSLGHQTKWGDOYHAHBETUXKNAMMWYDTILDWLPQTOX999', 'branchTransaction': 'NTCYZTAJTVJIAQW9JXUJCACYPHNMESWGWTANQQZSLGHQTKWGDOYHAHBETUXKNAMMWYDTILDWLPQTOX999', 'duration': 2}
```

The problem is when I am assigning those values to **attachToTangle** API, I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

My code is:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
import requests


trytes = "hello world!"
url="http://mydnsname:14265"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Accept": "application/json",
    'X-IOTA-API-Version': '1'
}

#get transactions
command = {
   "command": "getTransactionsToApprove",
   "depth": 4
}

data= json.dumps(command).encode("utf-8")
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
try:
    returnData = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    jsonData = json.loads(returnData)
    print (jsonData)
except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
    ResponseData = e.reason
    print (e)

#attach to tangle
command = {
   "command": "attachToTangle", 
"trunkTransaction": jsonData['trunkTransaction'],
"branchTransaction": jsonData['branchTransaction'],
"minWeightMagnitude": 9,
"trytes": trytes
}

data= json.dumps(command).encode("utf-8") 
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
try:
    returnData = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    jsonData = json.loads(returnData)
    print (jsonData)
except urllib.error.URLError as e: 
    ResponseData = e.reason
    print (e)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your `trytes` variable has to be a whole transaction encoded as trytes (so not only the text payload, but also address, amount, bundle hash etc...). Just passing random ASCII characters as trytes is not going to work.

Comment: Removed `pyota` tag, as this code is not using the PyOTA library (https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.py/) — although I recommend you give it a try; it might make things easier 

Comment: @mihi that means the entire bundle from "getTransactions" has to be converted into trytes?

Comment: @todofixthis Thank you for fixing this. I'm running IRI node, so I suppose I have to use IRI API for this?

Comment: I'd suggest using some client library (like PyOTA) for building your transactions and converting them to trytes. You cannot get your transactions from the IRI API since iri does not know what kind of transactions you want to publish.

Comment: If you are masochistic, you can of course build the transaction manually as well. See https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/100/what-is-the-iota-transaction-data-structure

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the suggestion. I tried with PyOTA and it worked!